# mocking beans in Configuration of a FeignClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I've got a Spring Cloud FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(name = "AccountSettingsClient", url = "${account.settings.service.url}", decode404 = true,
        configuration = AccountSettingsClientConfig.class, fallbackFactory = AccountSettingsClientFallbackFactory.class)
public interface AccountSettingsClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/settings/{uuid}",
            headers = "User-Agent=page/okhttp", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    AccountSettings accountSettings(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid);
}
```

The AccountSettingsClientConfig is:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
@EnableFeignClients
public class AccountSettingsClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor() {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), resource());
    }
}
```

Now in a integration test I need to mock the oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor bean and it doesn't work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        properties = {"account.settings.service.url=http://localhost:6565/users/accountsettings/"},
        classes = { AccountSettingsClientConfig.class,
                    HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class,
                    FeignAutoConfiguration.class, AccountSettingsClientIT.TestConfig.class })
@Slf4j
public class AccountSettingsClientIT {
    @Inject
    private AccountSettingsClient accountSettingsClient;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor() {
            return mock(RequestInterceptor.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also it with @MockBean, it was the same effect.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Hi Roman, this is a quite good questions, as I am also interested in the result! Maybe you could also ask the spring-cloud developers at https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud chat.

Comment: @UweGünther I did, see also https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2286

Comment: bit it looks like they do not have a solution either